# Array.reduce - strange behaviour with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

`myArr = ['a', 'b', 'c' ];
myArr.reduce((obj, val) => ({ ...obj, [val]: val }));`

Based on my understanding, you would expect the reduce to return `{ a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' }`

What we actually get back is `{ 0: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' }`

I tried putting a log inside to see what is going on with that first item, but the output is:

`b
c
{0: "a", b: "b", c: "c"}`

So now the behaviour is even more strange because we don't get any logs for the first `val` iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let myArr = ['a', 'b', 'c' ];
let result = myArr.reduce((obj, val) => ({ ...obj, [val]: val }), {});
console.log(result);
```

You missed the initial value to `reduce`. When no initial value is supplied, `reduce` pops off the first element for this purpose (and indeed no iteration happens; because `1+2+3` has two additions, not three, unless you specify we have to start from 0).

The first element is `"a"`, which deceptively becomes the misnamed `obj`; when you execute `{..."a", b: "b"}`, you will see that `..."a"` expanded in the object context will yield the characters' index as the key; thus, ..."a" is equivalent to `...{0: "a"}`.

Good thing you didn't try with `myArr = ['hello', 'world']` - that'd be much more of a surprise, I imagine (the result from that being `{0: "h", 1: "e", 2: "l", 3: "l", 4: "o", world: "world"}`).

Comment: This makes so much sense - had I tried it with a different array (like hello world as you mentioned) I'm sure I would have picked up on what was going on, but with a single character string my mind was blown. Cheers for the answer!